# Issue deploying react/node app to heroku with webpack build. Postinstall scripts running fine. Filepath suspected to be issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have a simple react/node app I am attempting to get deployed on heroku. My build is working properly however once on heroku, I will  either get 'Not Found" on the screen or in the console I get an error that says: unexpected token on line 1 of bundle.js.

I suspect that it is my file path being served up and my understanding is that file paths can be different in a dev environment compared to production. In my server.js file, I have two file paths, a '/' and a wildcard '*'. My server.js is nested in a server dir.

```
app.use(express.static('../client'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '../client/index.html'));
});


app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'index.html'));
});
```

In my dev environment this works fine. But I think the prod evnironment there seems to be an issue.

Here's my [repo](https://github.com/psbyron3/chatterup) so you can see my file structure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are no using es6, I think [this](http://ditrospecta.com/javascript/react/es6/webpack/heroku/2015/08/08/deploying-react-webpack-heroku.html) will help

Comment: @Dan looks like a great resource thanks! I ended up actually hosting with AWS. There was a steeper learning curve, but I don't have to keep a dev copy and a production copy of the app.